# HTML code work perfectly in JS bin editor but not in a new SharePoint page HTML

Tags: html, sharepoint

I have a problem, a page in HTML code works well in W3Schools and JS Bin editors, but does not work when it is   on page of SharePoint
The HTML code [Test Page](http://jsbin.com/botoqovexo/edit?html,output)  
The dropdown  and the button Berechnen are working well but in SharePoint the DropDown doesnot work, but the Berechnen Button work well. 
The HTML code ist the same as the link hier and on the SharePoint Page.
Thank you.

Comment: Hello, Can someone help me to solve this problem please?I will appreciate your help with this situation. Many Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if you need more examples or codes. I've tried everything what I really can within my knowledge, but it's not so much. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Keep your javascript after html and add everything in Content editor webpart it should work or give path of html page to content editor webpart.

Comment: yes, save as HTML, upload to doc lib somewhere, give path to webpart

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and tips. But I could not do what you suggest.I put the complete HTML in the XML Editor on SharePoint get this notice. **Diese Webpartausgabe kann einen HTML-<FORM>-Tag enthalten, der in diesem Webpart nicht unterstützt wird. Bearbeiten Sie den XML- oder XSLT-Quellcode, um das HTML-<FORM>-Tag zu entfernen. ** 
 The problem is with the Form, 
`  <form name="order">
    Size
    <select name="size" onchange="getCode();">
        <option value="22">22 mm</option>
        <option value="17">17 mm</option>

    </select>

Comment: Could you please send to me the complete code to put in the XML editor, thank you. I am not an expert on SharePoint, I am learning by doing

Comment: @Rob as you mentioned earlier you have working html file on your local system. Upload the same file in document library and give path of that document in content ediotr webpart.

Comment: I am a bit clumsy, or maybe a little more as a bit, but I cannot do what you mean, I know it is clear and should be easy but I cannot.
My first problem is, where “document library” in SharePoint is, and second problem is, which type of document should be on document library, and then my last problem; path for the document in content editor. 
How can I send print screen off my SharePoint?

Comment: Hey buddy.. its ok.. i understand your situation.. :) mail me on vaibhav045@gmail.com.. will guide u..